# How to install Windows 8.1 update KB3033055 after installing all available updates available to date?

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, windows-update

I have a computer with Windows 8 which has recently been formatted. Now I have gone through the two-day process of installing all available updates, and also Windows 8.1, with the goal to get to Windows 8.1 Update 3 which would bring back the start button to Windows.

Now I have found, that update KB3033055 would introduce this function. However, it was not installed during the update procedure and now the computer does not find any more updates. Manual installation after downloading "windows8.1-kb3033055-arm_1b0aeee420c6ad850de7cfac0c485d4bd7965f71.msu" does not work either (an error message shows up stating that this update is not available for this computer).

On the Microsoft page regarding this update I now have read that there are "known issues" with installation of this update:

> Symptom:
>   If you install KB3033055 (released September 2015) after installing any Monthly Rollup dated November 2017 or later, your device may not start up properly. 
>   Microsoft is working on a resolution and will provide an update in an upcoming release.
>
> Workaround: If you choose to install KB3033055, which is an optional update, we recommend that you install it before installing later update packages.

Well, of course I installed updates released after November 2017 already. How would I be able to install KB3033055 now? Or, in the worst case, if I would have to format the computer again and go through all the update procedure, how could I make sure to not install post-November 2017 updates again before installing KB3033055? Any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: What makes you think Windows 8.1 Update 3 isn't already installed?  It should have been installed through Windows Update.

Comment: I cannot find KB3033055 in the list of installed updates and neither has the function of activating the start button appeared in the property menu of the task bar.

Comment: The only infomration I can find indicate that update belongs to Windows RT not Windows 8.1

Comment: Oh .. yeah, that makes sense. I will check how I could install a "start button update" on a laptop and would close this question. Thank you!

Comment: If you have Windows 8, then updates for Windows 8.1, wouldn't be applicable.  Now you can upgrade to Windows 8.1, but an update for Windows RT 8.1 is only for Windows RT devices.

Comment: @Ramhound That was the solution, the update does not belong to Windows 8.1! Would you like to post an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I be able to install KB3033055 now?

If you have Windows 8, then updates for Windows 8.1, wouldn't be applicable.  KB3033055 is only applicable to Windows 8.1.  In order to install KB3033055 you need to upgrade to Windows 8.1.